# Executable jar closes immediately after launching (Slick2D)

Tags: java, slick2d

So I made an executable file with Eclipse but when I double-click it nothing happens. It IS NOT because I've got wrong association for running .jar files (I'm running okey my another jar program just by double-clicking it).
I also tried with command prompt and the console doesn't print anything at all and get back to be "normal".

I think it's something with main class so the thread doesn't last but closes after running (however it looks like the code isn't run because console would print lot of Slick stuff).

So here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shiftjumper shiftjumper = new Shiftjumper("Shiftjumper - behavior prototype");
    try {
        AppGameContainer gc = new AppGameContainer(shiftjumper);
        gc.setDisplayMode(TILE_SIZE*RIGHT_LEFT_TILES, TILE_SIZE*UP_DOWN_TILES, false);
        //gc.setTargetFrameRate(60);




        gc.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And here the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lwjgl.jar slick.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: engine.Shiftjumper
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download a tool known as JarSplice. JarSplice is a very simple GUI based application which packages all libraries and native code into the form of either a .JAR, a .EXE, a.SH or a .APP. Here is a link to the site: http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the jar in your terminal or command prompt, if there are any exceptions it will print to the console and you can debug